# Prove limit as $x$ goes to infinity of $(\cos x)/x =0$ using epsilon delta

Tags: calculus, analysis

How does one even go about doing this?

I know that I'm supposed to show that for some $M$, all $x$ greater than said $M$ ensure that $f(x)$ is within epsilon of $0$. But how does one do this rigorously?

Comment: $\cos x$ is bounded. Can you use this fact?

Comment: Use bounds on $\cos x $

Comment: The squeeze theorem would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$\left|\frac{\cos(x)}{x}\right|\le \frac1{|x|}$$

Answer (score 1):

Take $\epsilon > 0$ arbitrary. By the archimedean property, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{N} < \epsilon$.

So for all $x > N$, you have
\begin{equation*}
|\frac{\cos x}{x}| < \frac{1}{N} < \epsilon.
\end{equation*}